# ToAddress getting duplicated in emailing class

Tags: apex, email, apex-email-service, list, set

I have below emailing class where I am getting mails with my mail ID two times in **To** of the email generated. How can I make it place once in **To** section of the mail?

**Code:**

```
Public Set<String> tempSet = new Set<String>();
    Public List<String> sendTo = new List<String>();

    Public List<String> ccTo = new List<String>();

.........................................


   List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> mails = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
         List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> mailsDM = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
        for (Compliance_Incident_abv__c myContact :  [select ID,ManagerEmail_abv__c,RepEmail_abv__c,Rep_abv__c,Rep_abv__r.Name, Rep_abv__r.ManagerId,Rep_abv__r.Manager.Name from Compliance_Incident_abv__c  where ID =:oInc.id]) {
        sendTo.clear();
        ccTo.clear();  


      Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = 
      new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();


      sendTo.add(OneMap.get(mycontact.ID).RepEmail_abv__c); 
     // sendTo.add('anilkumar.lingaraju@abbvie.com');
      mail.setToAddresses(sendTo);


     mail.setSenderDisplayName('Abbvie IT Team');
         mail.SetSaveAsActivity(false);

      ccTo.add(OneMap.get(mycontact.ID).ManagerEmail_abv__c);
    // ccTo.add('sowmya.kashyap@abbvie.com');
      mail.setCcAddresses(ccTo);
      mail.setTargetObjectId(OneMap.get(mycontact.ID).Rep_abv__c);

      mail.setSubject('Resolution: Your ABS Incident has been closed in iREP');

      String body = 'Dear ' + OneMap.get(mycontact.ID).Rep_abv__r.Name + ', ';
      body += '<br><br>What you need to know:';
      body += '<br>ABS Incident '+ OneMap.get(mycontact.ID).Name +' has been closed';
      body += '<br>To view your open incidents:<br>';
      body += '•       Log into the IREP app on your iPad and select “Compliance Incidents”<br>';
      body += '•       Select the “Closed Incidents” View in the Compliance Incidents Home Page.<br>';
      body += '•       Click the Incident ID to view your incidents<br>';
      body += 'If you need assistance, please call the Field Help Desk at 1-800-344-6776.<br>';

      mail.setHtmlBody('<p style="font-family:Calibri;font-size:11px !important;">'+body+'</p>' );
      mails.add(mail);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely caused by your use of `setTargetObjectId` in addition to `setToAddresses`. `setTargetObjectId` is typically used in conjunction with an email template in order to populate merge fields, but since you're generating the email body in code, you can most likely remove it. When you use `setTargetObjectId`, the email address of the Contact/Lead/User record will also receive the email, even if the address has already been specified as a recipient by some other method (in this case your call to `setToAddresses`.

In other words...remove this line from your code:

```
mail.setTargetObjectId(OneMap.get(mycontact.ID).Rep_abv__c);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to handle this, the easiest is using a Set instead of a List.

```
Set<String> ccTo = new Set<String>();
ccTo.add(OneMap.get(mycontact.ID).ManagerEmail_abv__c);
```

As per the documentation, a Set handles the duplicate problem:

> **add(setElement)**
>
> Adds an element to the set if it is not already present.

This means you don't need to check the Set first to see if it contains a particular value.

You can then just construct a List from the Set when calling this method.

```
email.setCcAddresses(new List<String> (ccTo));
```

Comment: I did as you said as below.             Public Set<String> sendTo = new Set<String>(); sendTo.add(OneMap.get(mycontact.ID).RepEmail_abv__c);  mail.setToAddresses(new List<String> (sendTo));   Still getting duplicate emailIDs in To field.